# Firefox wont recognize fullwidth Polygon with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to achieve a polygon line made with javascript. The function that you see there below makes that polygon line and places it a top of the DIV contactPoly.

This function works perfectly on chrome and safari, but doesn't work on Firefox (IE is not supported). Here is a screenshot of a working example, on chrome

http://tinypic.com/r/k2grxg/8

And here is a link of a not working example on firefox.

http://tinypic.com/r/a493jm/8

As you can see Firefox doesn't seem to recognize 100% width of the window and cant place the breakpoints for the line. What I want to achieve is to make this work on Firefox
**JS**

```
function drawContactPolygon() {
            var docWidth = $(window).width();
            var aboutPolygon = Snap("##contactPoly");

            var polyline1 = aboutPolygon.polyline([0, 20, 0, 100, (docWidth*0.20), 100]);
            var polyline2 = aboutPolygon.polyline([-1000, 100, (docWidth*0.60), 20, (docWidth*0.60), 100]);
            var polyline3 = aboutPolygon.polyline([(docWidth*0.599), 20, (docWidth*0.75), 100, (docWidth*0.599), 100]);
            var polyline4 = aboutPolygon.polyline([(docWidth*0.75), 100, (docWidth), 100, (docWidth), 70]);

            polyline1.attr({fill: "##fff"});
            polyline2.attr({fill: "##fff"});
            polyline3.attr({fill: "##fff"});
            polyline4.attr({fill: "##fff"});
    }
    drawContactPolygon();
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="poly-cutout">
    <svg id="contactPoly"></svg>
</div>
```

**NOTES**
The line gets snapped on an SVG with the id="contactPolly" its a SVG, not an div.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**
I've tried to draw them on canvas, but I dindt get the elements on a full width base.

If you have any thoughts on how to fix it I would be very happy,

Kind regards

Comment: @RobertLongson sometimes, i'm doubting my skills. Thank you very kindly Robert!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add height="100%" width="100%" as attributes on the `<svg>` element.

At some point you'll need this for Chrome too as it's a Chrome bug that it doesn't work like Firefox does.